# C# dealing with HEX values, and binary conversion

Tags: c#, namespaces, binary, hex

is there a way to deal with HEX values (XORing values and shifting bytes, for example)
I need the whole program to deal with HEX only, and if the input is in Binary to convert it into HEX.

1. is there a HEX namespace ?
2. is there a way to represent a HEX other than using strings?

as I need to count the number of zeros and ones (for some tests I'm preforming), *without* the need to convert it into binary. so It doesn't matter how it looks as long there is a way to deal with it as HEX.

I need to know the possibility and my options.

Comment: Hex and binary are just convenient representations of the underlying voltage state of a transistor input. Applicability of bitwise operators is a completely independent concept.

Answer (score 2):

Hex, binary and decimal are different faces of the same objects, namely integers.

Parsing hex to int is done this way:

```
int i = int.Parse( "FFFFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber );
```

Converting int to hex string is done this way:

```
string s = i.ToString("x");
```

Defining a number in C# can be done using hex notation:

```
int i = 0xFFFFFF;
```

[BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) can also be used to store bytes. It does have an AND,OR,XOR  and NOT function.

Comment: @Amait Is your input a string of `0` and `1` that you need to parse as a number?

Comment: @Amait Convert.ToInt32("1000110101", 2).ToString("x");

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal (base-16), decimal (base-10), octal (base-8) etc mean *nothing* to the computer whatsoever. Wanting to get the computer to work "with HEX" is ... meaningless.

The most appropriate data format for working with raw data is in primitives such as `byte` (perhaps in a `byte[]`), or (arguably better) in larger composites such as `int` / `long` (which can allow for many performance savings, by allowing you to work with multiple values at the same time). Of course, if you are ***determined*** to work with `string` (which I do not recommend), for things such as "binary bit count" you could handle that at the character level simply by pre-computing the number of bits set in each of 0-9,A-F, and just doing a lookup against that value.

No, there is no "HEX" namespace, because it would be redundant. Hex is **just a number**; the number is the same number no matter how us weak-minded fleshy humans are thinking about it.  Likewise you could use similar pre-generated lookups for changing to/from numbers, or on-the-fly via:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("f3", 16); // hex to Int32
string hex = i.ToString("x2"); // Int32 to hex
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really been clear on what your input and output requirements are, and this reeks of homework, but:

```
        var x = 0x1111L;

        /// number of bits that are on
        var ones = 0;

        /// number of bits that are off
        var zeros = 0;

        var bitLength = Marshal.SizeOf(x) * 8;

        while (x > 0)
        {
            if ((x & 1) > 0)
            {
                ones++;
            }
            x >>= 1;
        }

        zeros = bitLength - ones;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} bits are on, {1} are off", ones, zeros);
```

Comment: no homework dude, I'm employed. and the client requirements are vague so before I  tell them its IMPOSSIBLE, i need to be sure and all you guys go back to deal with bits and bytes, so I am a bit relived. not what i'm looking for but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some "manual" approach

```
static void ConvertBinToHex(string hexadecimal)
{
    if (hexadecimal.Length == 0)
        return;

    string binary = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < hexadecimal.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (hexadecimal[i])
        {
            case '0': binary += "0000"; break;
            case '1': binary += "0001"; break;
            case '2': binary += "0010"; break;
            case '3': binary += "0011"; break;
            case '4': binary += "0100"; break;
            case '5': binary += "0101"; break;
            case '6': binary += "0110"; break;
            case '7': binary += "0111"; break;
            case '8': binary += "1000"; break;
            case '9': binary += "1001"; break;
            case 'A': binary += "1010"; break;
            case 'B': binary += "1011"; break;
            case 'C': binary += "1100"; break;
            case 'D': binary += "1101"; break;
            case 'E': binary += "1110"; break;
            case 'F': binary += "1111"; break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //remove leading zero's
    binary = binary.Trim('0');
    Console.WriteLine(binary);
}
```